# How to get the client ip address from browser in angular (typescript)

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, user-agent

Hey there I would really appreciate it if you can provide me with an example where a type script class can get the client's IP address and the browser that the client is using and set those values in variables

I want to do this in type script, not in javascript is that possible and if not how to do it with type script

-
So For Example I can

1. set those variables while submitting the form to the database in the back end
2. I can for example display for the user the browser he is using
   any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator

Comment: Check following answer. [This works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51924213/3578809) in 2020.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I took it as a basis for my problem but I did not solve it because it gave me the public IP of the internet server.
For an internal network with DHCP, change the URL by the following:

```js
getIpCliente(): Observable<string> {
  return this.http
             .get('http://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK')
             .map((res: Response) => {
               console.log('res ', res);
               console.log('res.json() ', res.text());
               console.log('parseado  stringify ', JSON.stringify(res.text()));
               let ipVar = res.text();
               let num = ipVar.indexOf(":");
               let num2 = ipVar.indexOf("\"});");
               ipVar = ipVar.slice(num+2,num2);

               return ipVar
             }
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not formatted as an answer - responses as this one belong in comments.

Comment: I marked you down because this answer returns a cors error

Comment: Aaron, I'm so sorry that it doesn't work for you, friend.
The application that takes the example is in production and without the problem that you mention.
Did you configure CORS in your back?
My back is done in springboot and the following helped me:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

I hope it works
Greetings, Juan-

Comment: If you're receiving a CORs error calling the api.ipify.org endpoint from angular, check the headers being sent.  You can always send a second parameter to the http.get call that clears to the default headers: this.httpClient.get(url, { headers: null }).   Also check if your angular application has an httpInterceptor that may be injecting additional authorization headers.

Comment: After deployment hitting using proxy giving me server IP and hitting directly, the blocked content issue also tried with "{ headers: null }" but nothing works. Any solution?

Comment: Why do we need to have an external API call needed for getting the ip-address. Does it possible to retrieve the IP address in our application instead of making the rest call to `api.ipify.org`?

Answer (score 5):

Try the services of https://geolocation-db.com to get the public ip address of the user.

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

this.http.get<any>('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
  .pipe(
    catchError(err => {
      return throwError(err);
    }),
    tap(response => {
      console.log(response.IPv4);
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try like this

```
var json = 'http://ipv4.myexternalip.com/json';
   $http.get(json).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.data.ip)
},  function(e) {
   alert("error");
});
```

Comment: OR    try this networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) { 
    alert(ip); 
});

Comment: thanks for answer hamad but this is not working in type script class

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

Create Provider and add function with required dependencies :

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


 //  Function :

getIP(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://ipinfo.io') // ...using post request
    .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
}
```

Controller Code :

```
getIP() {
    this.loading = true;
    this._myIPService.getIP()
    .subscribe(
        IPDetails => this.IppDetails,
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}
```

You will have all the details of IP in `this.IppDetails`

Comment: thanks for your answer but why should i provide id parameter in the service while i should be getting data from the server ,i dont think that getIP(id) ,is a right signature in our case

Comment: That's​ my typing mistake, no need of id

Comment: so what does this return a string an object or what exactly ?

Comment: It returns json object

Comment: I'm sure it does work, I am using it for 3 months now, You must have missed something.